# What is = followed by == operation?

Tags: octave

I've encountered this code and don't know what its performing :

```
yk = y == k;
```

Recreating :

```
>> a = 1
a =  1
>> b = 2
b =  2
>> c = 3
c =  3
>> a = b == c
a = 0
>>
```

I think it is a boolean operation. `If y == k then yk = 1 else yk = 0` ?

Comment: Yes. the result of the boolean operation `y == k` is assigned (`=`) to `yk`

Comment: a is 0, because b == c is false.

Comment: @Suever I thought I was in the C++ tab... :(

Comment: @user2899162 No worries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to figure out what your statement means, you can refer to [Octave's operator precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Operator-Precedence.html). As you can see from that list, assignment (`=`) has the lowest precedence of any operator (including `==`). As a result, the line that you have posted translates to

1. Perform the relational operation `y == k`
2. Assign the result to the variable `yk`